# ui-mask clear whole input on backspace

Tags: angularjs

I have an input with a [ui-mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask) for CNIC. It is working fine for normal flow but when I use backspace at start of input, It removes whole input at once. How can I stop this behavior?

here is my input field

```
<input type="text" id="txtCNIC" ui-mask="99999-9999999-9" name="txtCNIC">
```

**Edit: Official Demo**

[Here is official demo](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask/master/demo/index.html) of this, it is working same here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Cnic" ui-mask="99999-9999999-9"  ui-mask-placeholder ui-mask-placeholder-char="_"/>
```

Try this